# Jquery If/Then in Click Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, onclick

This is what I want it to do...

When div called 'bd' is clicked > check if the div with id of 'ump' has a class of 'active' >
if it does, get div with class of 'brandDump' and slide it up slowly, hide it, and remove the class of 'active' > else, take the div with class 'brandDump' and slide it down, show it, and add class of 'active'

Nothing is happening when I click div.bd. What am I doing wrong?

Fiddle link and code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/K2V8f/36/

```
<div class="bd">cool</div>
<div class="brandDump" id="ump">works</div>
<div>shape</div>

.brandDump {
background-color:#fff;
width:100px;
display:none;
}

.bd {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:#000;
}

$(".bd").click(function () {
if ("#ump".hasClass("active")) {
    $(".brandDump").slideUp("slow");
    $(".brandDump").hide();
    $(".brandDump").removeClass("active");
} else {
    $(".brandDump").slideDown("slow");
    $(".brandDump").show();
    $(".brandDump").addClass("active");
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2V8f/43/)

You need to use callbacks when the slideUp finishes.

```
$(".bd").click(function () {
    if ($("#ump").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".brandDump").slideUp("slow", function () {
            $(".brandDump").removeClass("active");
        });

    } else {
        $(".brandDump").slideDown("slow", function () {
            $(".brandDump").addClass("active");
        });

    }

});
```

Also there was an error with ("#ump")... should have been $("#ump")

Comment: Note that there's no need to call `.hide()` and `.show()` because the sliding functions already handle that.

Comment: p/s: It's good to learn that you can chain methods in jQuery http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you had:

```
"#ump".hasClass(...
```

...when you should've had:

```
$("#ump").hasClass(...
```

But note also that the `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` methods hide and show your element(s) so you don't need to call `.hide()` and `.show()` as well. Also it is more efficient to chain jQuery methods together if you want them to operate on the same element:

```
$(".bd").click(function () {
    if ($("#ump").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".brandDump").slideUp("slow")
                       .removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $(".brandDump").slideDown("slow")
                       .addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K2V8f/50/

> *"check if the div with id of 'ump' has a class of 'active' > if it does, get div with class of 'brandDump' and slide it up slowly"*

The div with id `ump` is the *same* div as the one with class `brandDump`. I'm not sure why you're talking about them as if they're two different divs when in fact your code seems to then use the `#ump` and `.brandDump` selectors interchangeably to select the one div, but if you treat them as one more consistently **you can cut your function down to one line:**

```
$(".bd").click(function () {
    $(".brandDump").slideToggle("slow").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K2V8f/51/